Phase of a coherent state in Quantum Mechanics
In the following image from Section II of the paper Mesoscopic Superposition of States with Sub-Planck Structures in Phase Space, the second state is designated by $\left|e^{i\theta}\alpha\right>$ to represent that the state is in the $\theta$ phase with the state $\left|\alpha\right>$, where $\left|\alpha\right>$ is a coherent state.
How is this state different from the state $e^{i\theta}\left|\alpha\right>$?
For context, the superposed state $\left|\psi\right>$ in the image is the so-called cat state. According to Wikipedia, $\left|e^{i\theta}\alpha\right>$ and $e^{i\theta}\left|\alpha\right>$ are not the same. Could someone explain how they differ?


To see the difference, all you need to do is write the two states as a series, as is done on the cat state page.

One is a global phase, the other is a rotation of the state in phase space.
Using the definition of the coherent state:
$$
|\alpha\rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2}|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle, \qquad \alpha = |\alpha|e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C},
$$
and taking for example $\theta = \pi$ and evaluating the inner product $\langle\alpha|e^{i\theta}\alpha\rangle$ we see that
$$
\langle\alpha|-\alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{\alpha^{n}(\alpha^*)^m}{\sqrt{n!m!}}\langle m|n\rangle =
 e^{-|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{|\alpha|^{2n}}{n!} = e^{-2|\alpha|^2} 
$$
which for large $\alpha$ goes to zero, meaning $|\alpha\rangle$ and $-|\alpha\rangle$ are almost orthogonal. However, clearly
$$
|(-|\alpha\rangle)^{\dagger} |\alpha\rangle|^2 = 1
$$
since in this case the phase is global.

It is only a global phase if you rotate both the ket and the bra the same way. If you only rotated one of them, then you ought to get something different.

Yes of course, $|\alpha\rangle \pm |-\alpha\rangle$ are two orthogonal states, but clearly $|\alpha\rangle - |\alpha\rangle = 0$.
